# C++: File I/O Look for name in file

Tags: c++

I have this function designed to look for a name in a csv type txt file.

```
void LookupName( string tname ){ //Checks for name in records.txt and enters it if it does not exist
//Pointers
string * names; //Pointer to dynamically created array of names

//Variables
short numLines = 0; //Stores the number of lines in the file
string throwaway = " "; //String used to throw away unwanted content from file
bool found = false; //Used to track if a name is found int he file

//objects
ifstream file ("records.txt"); //Open the file


if (file.is_open()) {

    //Count the number of lines
    numLines = count(istreambuf_iterator<char>(file), istreambuf_iterator<char>(), '\n'); 

    //Reset cursor position
    file.close();
    file.open("records.txt");

    //Create arrays
    names = new string[numLines]; 

    //Loop through the file and fill arrays
    for ( short i; i < numLines; i++ ) {
        getline (file, names[i], ','); //Fill name
        getline (file, throwaway ); //Throw the rest of the line away
    }

    //Loop through names to find the name that was entered
    for ( short i; i < numLines; i++ ) {
        if (names[i] == tname) { // if the name is found
            found = true; //return true
        }
    }

    if ( found == false ) { //if the name is not found
        //This works
        file.close();
        ofstream ofile("records.txt", ios::app);
        ofile << tname << ",0,0\n"; //Add it to the file with 0 wins and losses
        ofile.close();
    }

    //Cleanup
    file.close();
    delete [] names;

} 
}
```

For some reason apparently beyond my ability to debug, this doesn't work; however, when I remove the second for loop and combine it with the first one it does work. ( This is how I fully intend to leave it because it doesn't need to be segmented into 3 loops but I'd like to know why for my own education):

Working:

```
void LookupName( string tname ){ //Checks for name in records.txt and enters it if it does not exist
//Pointers
string * names; //Pointer to dynamically created array of names

//Variables
short numLines = 0; //Stores the number of lines in the file
string throwaway = " "; //String used to throw away unwanted content from file
bool found = false; //Used to track if a name is found int he file

//objects
fstream file ("records.txt"); //Open the file


if (file.is_open()) {

    //Count the number of lines
    numLines = count(istreambuf_iterator<char>(file), istreambuf_iterator<char>(), '\n'); 

    //Reset cursor position
    file.close();
    file.open("records.txt", fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::app );

    //Create arrays
    names = new string[numLines]; 

    //Loop through the file and fill arrays
    for ( short i; i < numLines; i++ ) {
        getline (file, names[i], ','); //Fill name
        getline (file, throwaway ); //Throw the rest of the line away

        if (names[i] == tname) { // if the name is found
            found = true; //return true
        }

    }

    if ( found == false ) { //if the name is not found
        //This works
        file << tname << ",0,0\n"; //Add it to the file with 0 wins and losses
    }

    //Cleanup
    file.close();
    delete [] names;

} 
}
```

Anyone care to weigh in on why this is happening?

edit: Also, since I'm asking questions ( I was really trying not to ) is there a way to push the cursor back to the top of a file without opening and closing it?

edit 2: Is there a way to tell the program to ignore the remainder of a csv type line, I onyl want the first item on the line for this particular function and I feel using a throwaway string might not be the optimal way.

edit3: updated to use fstream rather than 1 if and 1 of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several points to remark on the code, hoping this will help you make the code more manageable (and debuggable). But first, to answer one of your questions - yes you can set the current position in the file by using [seekg](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/seekg/).

1. better use `std::vector` - you don't need to read the file twice and avoid managing memory by yourself, which is very bug-prone
2. why do you read the whole list into the memory if you only need to check if the name is there? Just read it into THE SAME string each iteration, compare and break out/continue.
3. remember that `getline` reads everything from the beginning of line, including spaces. This might be the reason why your program does not work.
4. [style] void `LookupName` function? The function is called `lookup` but actually does nothing if it finds what it looks up. I'd suggest `AddName`
5. what about error handling? you just do nothing when you can't open the file which signals "all is good". Return an error status or throw an exception
6. re debugging try just printing both strings in each iteration, surrounded by quotes so that you can see the white space, e.g. `cout << '"' << name << '"';`. Good chances that you'll see the problem right away.

HTH, enjoy

Comment: Lot of good information, the reason the code was having issues was in the for loops. Notice it's "short i" not "short i = 0" But I will definitely take advantage of your input!

Comment: I updated it to use 1 string, it was loading the entire file because it was c&p from a function that needed to load the entire file. Did not change the name out of laziness. Changes to 1 string eliminated need for vector (which I'm admittedly too lazy to learn how to use right now) and I did try to cout but the loop was never getting called because I was being read as already larger then numLines due to not being initialized correctly. On error handling: This is an intro to c++ course and the code goes way above as it is. I'll worry about that later. This information did help a bunch so thanks